# Отправка формы, AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

При нажатии на кнопку форма должна пройти валидацию и отправиться на сервер. Валидация работает, а вот с отправкой формы проблема - нет запроса на сервер.
HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(null);" id="form">
    <input class="form form_name" type="text" name="name" required="" 
placeholder="Type your name">
    <input class="form form_" type="text" name="secondname" required="" 
placeholder="Type your secondname">
    <input class="form form_" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your e-mail">
    <select class="form form_select" name="gender" required="">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form form_" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Type your password">
    <p class="form__p"><input class="form form_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check" value="ok" required="">Sith Code</p>
    <div id="result" class="form__answer"></div>
    <button type="button" class="form form_submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "val"
});
var form = $( "#form" );
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form").validate({

       rules:{

            name:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20,
            },

            secondname:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 20,
            },
            email:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            gender:{
                required: true,
            },
            pass:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 10,
            },
            checkbox:{
                required: true,
            },

       }

    });
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
      if(form.val()) {
            var msg = $("#form").serialize();
            console.log(msg);
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://codeit.pro/frontTestTask/user/registration',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status === 'OK') {window.location.href='second_page.html'}
                else {alert(data.message)};
              }
            });
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: Запрос происходит? Или запроса вообще не происходит? А `console.log(msg)` срабатывает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Запрос вообще не происходит. console.log() не срабатывает

Comment: Тогда вам логично подумать, что не происходит клику, там и ищите проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в этих двух строках:

```
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        if(form.val()) {
```

Вместо прослушивания кнопки рекомендую слушать форму на событие `submit`. А также вопрос - откуда у формы взялся метод `.val()`, который возвращает значение поля ввода? У формы такого поведения нет.

Вместо этих двух строк следует сделать так:

```
$(document).on('submit', form, function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // чтобы форма не отправилась по умолчанию
    var data = form.serialize();
    // и дальше код отправки запроса по аякс
});
```

Событие `submit` срабатывает при любой попытке отправить форму. А поскольку уже есть работающий валидатор, то он не должен пропустить до события `submit`, пока форма не пройдет валидацию.

И еще поменять

```
<button type="button" class="form form_submit" id="submit">Send</button>
```

на

```
<button type="submit" class="form form_submit" id="submit">Send</button>
```